# data not loading onto list from API [ReactJs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so I am currently working on an admin control panel that retrieves objects from an API.

The API has two different endpoints, it's either of:

```
http://localhost:3000/videos
http://localhost:3000/manuals
```

And the API's both return objects with sets of data such as "id, url, title and thumbnailUrl"

I have a module that's responsible for the card that has the following code:

```
export interface Manual {
  id?: string | number;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail?: string | null;
}
```

I have a module that's responsible for creating the actual HelpCard components
And then the HelpCard components are then loaded up into my HelpList component 
And then finally, I have my HelpAdmin.view module that brings it all together

The issue is, even when I call a

```
console.log(this.props.data);
```

within my HelpList module, I am returned with 8 empty arrays that look like so:

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am curious as to why my video / manual cards are not actually being displayed onto my list?

Thank you in advance for reading and helping.

Comment: In HelpAdminView you have empty  manuals and videos in state, and you pass this empty array to your HelpList  component. But as I see you get the videos and manuals by calling api in HelpList component.

Comment: @SuleymanSah So how would you suggest I go about fixing this?

Comment: it is difficult to explain in comments, so I added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manuals and videos data is in your HelpList component's state, but you are using this.props.data.map which comes empty from your HelpListAdmin using  data={this.state.videos}.

So you need replace the related code like this in your HelpList component's render.

```
              {this.state.manuals.map((card: Manual) => (
                <HelpCard
                  card={card}
                  key={card.id}
                  deleteProduct={this.props.onDelete}
                  editProduct={this.props.onEdit}
                  type={this.props.type}
                />
              ))}
```

But if you want to manage the state in your HelpAdminView component, you need to make the api calls in this component instead of HelpList component.

And I think you should keep the state in parent (HelpAdminView) and pass the manuals and videos to the HelpList component.

So you need to move this code from HelpList to HelpAdminView.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ card: res.data });
    this.loadAdminHelpCard("videos");
    this.loadAdminHelpCard("manuals");

    //console.log(res.data);
  }


  loadAdminHelpCard = (type: "videos" | "manuals"): void => {
    const baseApiUrl = `http://localhost:3000`;
    const url = `${baseApiUrl}/${type}`;
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ [type]: res.data } as any);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Remove the state in HelpList component.

And pass the videos and manuals as props (like you did now) to HelpList component.

```
      <div className="listDisplay">
            <div>
              <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <h2>Videos</h2>
              </div>
              <HelpList
                data={this.state.videos}
                type="videos"
                onEdit={this.editProduct}
                onDelete={this.deleteProduct}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <h2>Manuals</h2>
              </div>
              <HelpList
                data={this.state.manuals}
                type="manuals"
                onEdit={this.editProduct}
                onDelete={this.deleteProduct}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

And use this props in HelpList component (as you did now).

```
export default class HelpList extends Component<Props, State> {

  static props: any;

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.card ? (
          <div className="row">
            {this.props.data.map((card: Manual) => (
              <HelpCard
                card={card}
                key={card.id}
                deleteProduct={this.props.onDelete}
                editProduct={this.props.onEdit}
                type={this.props.type}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>
            <br></br>Loading Cards...
          </h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the API in HelpList Component and setting it to state
In your HelpAdminView component you have a state of manuals that is an empty array and passing it as a data prop, it would remain empty as you are not updating it,

You can do your API calling in HelpAdminView component and then pass it as a prop to your HelpList component

Hope it helps

Comment: So you're saying I should do the LoadAdminHelpCard function within my HelAdminView?

Comment: yes, then you would pass card in props to. call the api in the container

Comment: ibtsam, I have edited my question to show the follow up, I hope you can help more

Comment: Oh, I just had to declare "loadAdminHelpCard={this.loadAdminHelpCard}" within my <HelpList /> component call and it seems to call my cards now, but the cards are empty, no title, imageurl or url is set.

Comment: I have also added the code that's responsible for creating the cards to the edited section of my question.

Comment: are you passing card prop to HelpList component ?